# Problemas con el valor de retorno de getmonth()

Tags: javascript, date

Tengo un problema con el valor del mes, específicamente esta fecha '2017-11-01', las demás fechas me funcionan bien, contabilizo datos por mes para realizar estadísticas y tengo el problema porque en esta fecha getmonth() me retorna el valor de 9 como si fuera octubre, si coloco '2017-11-02' si me toma el valor de 10, no he revisado si es así con todos los días 1 de cada mes, de antemano agradezco a quienes puedan ayudarme

```
var fecha=new Date('2017-11-01');
console.log(fecha.getmonth());
```

Comment: Puede ser un error debido a tu zona horaria. Prueba con `getUTCMonth()` para descartar esa posibilidad.

Comment: muchas gracias , si se resolvió el problema

Answer (score 0):

En la documentación se dice que:

> El método [`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getMonth) devuelve el mes del objeto `Date` según la hora
> local, donde el número cero indica el primer mes del año.

Es posible entonces que tu problema sea debido a una diferencia de horas en tu zona horaria.

Para evitar esto puedes usar [`getUTCMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth), que te devolverá el mes de acuerdo al [Tiempo Universal Coordinado (UTC)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_universal_coordinado).

---

### Recomendación

Si vas a trabajar mucho con fechas y horas en Javascript, te recomiendo usar la librería [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com). Es una librería ligera y que facilita el trabajo con fechas y horas.

Comment: muchas gracias por la recomendación, de verdad me ha servido bastante